# I don't want my PC mouse pointer to stop at edges of the screen, instead it should appear on the other edge

Tags: windows, mouse-cursor

I wonder if I can move the cursor to an edge of the screen and immediately pops out on the opposite edge..like as in "3DS Max" software UI, while changing values by dragging the combo box of 3ds max.

If this feature is enabled by a registry tweak or similar tweaks, then let's assume my pointer is at the top & I want to click a tray icon(which is at the bottom), then I can move my mouse upwards a little bit...this would be easier in "After Effects" UI while seeking frames by dragging the dotted-timeline.. I'm using Windows 7 x64.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be called "edge wrap" or "wrap around".

*Assuming Windows* (since you didn't say), one such tool is [Edgeless](http://lifehacker.com/5254236/edgeless-enables-mouse-cursor-wrap-around), another is [CursorUS](http://www.loonies.narod.ru/cursorus.htm).

Comment: I would be interested to know how this software handles situations such as dragging a Window (folder, browser, word doc, etc...) to the edge of the screen. In Windows 7 do you lose the Aero Snap functionality?

Comment: CursorUS perfectly snap windows as usual, and it snaps perfectly..and can be manually override while holding ctrl key. While holding down the left mouse button(usually for dragging), CursorUs disables itself..and activates when the button is released..